# installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status - R packge or R studio

Tags: r, devtools, libgit2, gert

R version 3.4.4. Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

**install.packages('devtools')**
The output shows missing "gert", "usethis".

Then I tried to install the failed packages "gert".

**install.packages('gert', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')**

Output is an error of missing "libgit2-dev".

Next, I went to install "libgit2-dev", and failed all the time.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65433724/configuration-failed-to-find-libgit2-library) help?

Comment: How exactly did you try to install "libgit2-dev"? That's not an R package. That's a system dependency. Also, is there a reason you are using such an old version of R?

Comment: Good reminder. A few packages was demanding older version. I will try to find updated version if exits.

Comment: It is 2021. Why are you using an R binary from 2017 that is four major releases behind?  Why an Ubuntu release that is outdated?  And if you use those, why not stick _with the outdated devtools from the same period_?  `sudo apt-get install r-cran-devtools`.

Comment: Good reminder. My ubuntu system is 18.04, this means, I could choose R version 3.4 or 3.6. Some packages I had prefer older R version. I will  find updated suits if exits.

Comment: See https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html and read the first few paragrapghhs carefully,  You can get R 4.0.3 via `apt-get` for 18.04 too.  That said, I prefer current versions -- running 20.10 here.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel Grateful for your comments. Update work continues also in Ubuntu.

Comment: Still grateful to the precious comments from experts. 
These happened afterwards: 
I updated the ubuntu system to 20.04 (cpu is intel.) , updated the R version to 4.0 and Rstudio version as well. Then, non of the mentioned packages could be installed, including ggplot2, tidyverse, dplyr etc. Therefore, all the packages were reinstalled, until now. Hope something will work out. I will check as soon I go back.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of failure of installing "libgit2" is, one shall install the "git2r" instead. (Reference: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2 and https://github.com/ropensci/git2r)

** Solve the "gert" below:**

**install.packages('git2r')** # [https://github.com/ropensci/git2r\](https://github.com/ropensci/git2r%5C)
**install.packages('gert')**\

below refers to: https://github.com/r-lib/gert the installation hints.
On Linux you need to install libgit2:

Debian: libgit2-dev
Fedora / CentOS: libgit2-devel
For Ubuntu Trusty and Xenial, you can use libgit2 backports from 
this ppa:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cran/libgit2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgit2-dev

DONE!

After that, the package "usethis" can be installed normally. 
**install.packages('usethis')**
DONE!

In the end, the "devtools" can also be installed normally.
**install.packages('devtools')**\

The error of "non-zero status" does not show up.
**library(devtools)**
Loading required package: usethis

Extend story:
the package tidyverse can be intalled successfully after the devtools problem got solved.

Happy end.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It is a useful site. But this is not really a useful answer because you just show what the maintainer (jeroen) provided for you with that PPA for your (seriously outdated) version of Ubuntu.

Comment: With the hints from other users, problem is solved soon after posted. Maybe helpful to leave it like this a.t.m.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel good to know it is seriously outdated, thanks telling me. Let me check out the more up to date info.