# Installing devtools package fails

Tags: r, devtools

I am trying to install the package called devtools. I run the command:
`install.packages("devtools")` or `install.packages("devtools",dependencies = TRUE)` and I get the same error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gert’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'gert', details:
  call: NULL
  error: 'as_text' is not an exported object from 'namespace:sys'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/ab/usr/my_user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/gert’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gert’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘gert’ is not available for package ‘usethis’
* removing ‘/ab/usr/my_user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/usethis’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘usethis’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘usethis’ is not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/ab/usr/my_user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/devtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpj3P5T5/downloaded_packages’
```

I've tried running `install.packages("gert")` and i get error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gert’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'gert', details:
  call: NULL
  error: 'as_text' is not an exported object from 'namespace:sys'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Here is some systemInfo():

R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

I've looked through similar questions where commenters/answerers suggested closing and opening Rstudio or restarting the R session. I have tried those and gotten back the same error.

Comment: Your r version is quite old. Can you update?

Comment: unfortunately, no. I will look into it but i am not very hopeful.

Comment: okay. devtools pulls in a bunch of packages, which in turn also do. Possible one of these doesn't play nice with an older r version. Also some packages have system requirements.

Comment: You could try to reinstall `sys` as well. I think the error about `sys::as_text` is a red herring, frankly, since it was added to that package 2y or so ago, but perhaps the installation got dorked.

Comment: downloaded custom R install using latest version of R. works now

Answer (score 1):

Updating R to latest version worked.

Answer (score 0):

Installing libgit2 (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65853618/installation-of-package-devtools-had-non-zero-exit-status-r-packge-or-r-stud)) worked for me.

There is also a conda package for it which works just as well, in case you don't have sudo rights.

Answer (score 0):

Adding one failure possibility for people to check:

I had the package installation fail out of a sudden. After many trials and errors, I realized that it was a simple line in the Description file. Also, the description section of the file needs to have 4 space tab when starting a new line.